# Users fail to authenticate into Sharepoint 2010 when there are accent marks in the Lotus Notes user name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ibm-domino

I posted this on StackOverflow but was told this is a more appropriate forum.

Our Sharepoint users use their email address and Lotus Notes password to log in. This is working just fine except for one case: if their Lotus Notes user name contains an accent mark, the authentication fails.

I logged LDAP activity in Notes and see it failing. Here's an example:

The actual username is: René Testing/Employee/LW-US

What the activity log shows LDAP is receiving is the following:

User Name:  CN=RenÃ© Testing/OU=Employee/O=LW-US

Any thoughts on how to debug the problem?

thanks clem

Comment: The first thing I would do is set LDAPDEBUG=7 on the Domino server, then try logging into Sharepoint twice: once with my own email address & password, and once with the failing user's email address and password. Comparing the output could help pin down the problem. Unfortunately, you can't really trust that what you see in the logged output for accented characters is accurate, because it could be converted differently for logging than it is for the actual protocol, therefore my next step would be to use an LDAP client to issue the exact query shown in the log and examine the results that way.

Comment: I was about to do this when I tried one thing and the account was able to log into SP.  This isn't a fix, but it might get us past the issue until I have time to investigate further.

I added "Rene Testing" (not accent) as the first entry of the 'user name' field.  So Now, it looks like this:

Rene Testing, 
René Testing/Employee/LW-US, 
René Testing.

Doing this allowed me to log into Sharepoint.  

Clem